# I do not know why my simulation is so slow. I need to optimize my simulation and improve the way I use variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, pypy

This is a python program that does some sort of simulation,, I am looking for any type of optimization while keeping the same p[i] form, I have tried Pypy and I got an around 3x performance gain over python. Any suggestions are welcomed

```py
import random
from time import perf_counter
infected, non_infected = 1, 99999
infectation_chance, infection_days, death_chance = 1/100, 2/1000, 2/100
population, population_list = infected + non_infected, non_infected * [0] + infected * [1]
place = 10
p = {i: [] for i in range(1,place + 1)}
day = 1
simulation_duration = 3
while 0 < simulation_duration:
    print(f"Working on day {day}..")
    time1 = perf_counter()
    for person in population_list:
        p[random.randint(1, place)].append(person)
    time2 = perf_counter()
    i = 0
    while i < place:
        tl = []
        i += 1
        for crowd in p[i]:
            if crowd == 0:
                 if (random.random() < infectation_chance * str(p[i]).count("1")) - (infectation_chance/100 * str(p[i]).count("0")):
                     tl.append(1)
                 else:
                    tl.append(0)
            if crowd == 1:
                tl.append(1)
        p[i] = tl

    i = 0
    population_list = []
    while i < place:
        i += 1
        population_list.append(p[i])
    simulation_duration -= 1
    day += 1
    print(f"Total time: {perf_counter() - time1} \nInfection time: {perf_counter() - time2} \nPlacing time: {time2-time1}")
print(str(population_list).count("1"), str(population_list).count("0"))
```

Even tho I received lots of help I still need more optimization.Any type of optimization as far as it doesn't change the results are welcomed.Since this is fully compatible with pypy I am using pypy, I can also use python if it means better performance. Current setup:

```py
import random
import functools
from time import perf_counter

with open("results.txt", "w") as results:
    results.seek(0)
    results.write("")
    results.close()
    time1 = perf_counter()

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def simulation():
    infected, non_infected = 1, 99999999
    infectation_chance_c, death_chance, recovery_chance, reinfectation_chance, incubation_time = 1.4, 1 - 0.03, 1 - 0.97, 1 - 1 / 150, 2
    death_chance, recovery_chance = death_chance / incubation_time, recovery_chance / incubation_time
    population_total, population_list = infected + non_infected, non_infected * [0] + infected * [1]
    place = 1
    day = 0
    simulation_duration = 100000000
    with open("results.txt", "a") as results:
        print("Starting... \nPlease wait for results, this can take lots of time!")
        while infected > 0  and simulation_duration > 0:
            population = population_list.count(0) + population_list.count(-1) + population_list.count(1)
            healthy = population_list.count(0) + population_list.count(-1)
            recovered = population_list.count(-1)
            infected = population_list.count(1)
            died = population_total - len(population_list)
            p = {i: [] for i in range(1,place + 1)}
            results.write(f"Day {day}: Infected: {infected} Healthy: {healthy} p-Imune: {recovered} Alive: {population} Died: {died} \n")
            print(f"Day {day}: Infected: {infected} Healthy: {healthy} p-Imune: {recovered} Alive: {population} Died: {died}")
            for person in population_list:
                p[random.randint(1, place)].append(person)
            i = 0
            while i < place:
                i += 1
                p_infected = p[i].count(1)
                try:
                    infectation_chance =  1 - float(p_infected) / (float(len(p[i])) / infectation_chance_c)
                except:
                    pass
                for j, crowd in enumerate(p[i]):
                    if crowd == -1:
                        if random.random() > reinfectation_chance:
                            p[i][j] = 1
                        elif random.random() > reinfectation_chance:
                            p[i][j] = 0
                    elif crowd:
                        if random.random() > death_chance:
                            p[i].pop(j)
                        elif random.random() > recovery_chance:
                            if random.random() > 0.4:
                                p[i][j] = -1
                            else:
                                p[i][j] = 0
                    elif not crowd:
                        if random.random()>infectation_chance:
                            p[i][j] = 1



            i = 0
            population_list = []
            while i < place:
                i += 1
                population_list.extend(p[i])
            simulation_duration -= 1
            day += 1
            print(f"Total time: {perf_counter() - time1}")
simulation()
print(f"Simulation finishsed... \nProcessing time: {perf_counter()-time1}")
```

Comment: You mean PyPy implementation, right? PyPI is a package repository.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Yes sorry, I meant Pypy

Comment: Is there more info on what this code should do, besides "some sort of simulation"? The usual approach for optimizing numerical Python without modifying algorithms is using NumPy or the many scientific computing packages for Python

Comment: As for the speed, CPython just lacks the type inference and optimizations used by the fast compiled implementations/languages, so there's a limit to how much you can optimize your Python code. That's why so many Python libraries implement the core computations in C or use PyPy, Numba, Cython, etc. If you stick to CPython, we're stuck with small improvements like changing p from a dict with integer keys to a list `p = [[] for i in range(place + 1)]`, though you'll have to ignore `p[0]` (or make a 1-based index class that wraps your 0-indexed list, or custom getindex, but that's a hassle).

Comment: The simulation is of a virus, in the way I see stuff it calculates how many people get infected. Randomly puts the population in the specified number of rooms, for every room calculates the chance for every person to get infected.The problem is that idk how to use NumPy.

Comment: @BatWannaBe thanks for explaining. I am quite new to this, if you could also find the problems in my code would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (random.random() < infectation_chance * str(p[i]).count("1")) - (infectation_chance/100 * str(p[i]).count("0"))` is always true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a corrected version in pure python, commented because there were some bugs. your major time loss was counting infected/non-infected inside the for loop, though the result is always the same. it could be optimized again with numpy if you wanna use a bigger population

```
import random
from time import perf_counter
infected, non_infected = 1, 99999
infectation_chance, infection_days, death_chance = 1/100, 2/1000, 2/100
population, population_list = infected + non_infected, non_infected * [0] + infected * [1]
place = 10
day = 1
simulation_duration = 3
while 0 < simulation_duration:
    # p must be reset here or it will grow indefinitely
    p = {i: [] for i in range(1,place + 1)}
    print(f"Working on day {day}..")
    time1 = perf_counter()
    for person in population_list:
        p[random.randint(1, place)].append(person)
    time2 = perf_counter()
    i = 0
    while i < place:
        i += 1
        # if you need to, count infected/non-infected here
        # not in your for loop where it has always the same value
        # and don't cast to str, what's the point?
        # pi_infected = p[i].count(1)
        # pi_sane = p[i].count(0)
        for j, crowd in enumerate(p[i]):
            if crowd == 0:
                # your formula was broken (a-b is always true)
                # i used a generic one
                if random.random()>(1-infectation_chance):
                    # change your list in place:
                    # no need for temp list, save lots of cycles
                    p[i][j] = 1

    i = 0
    population_list = []
    while i < place:
        i += 1
        # it's extend, not append here or your population list
        # will have a length of #place
        population_list.extend(p[i])
    simulation_duration -= 1
    day += 1
    print(f"Total time: {perf_counter() - time1} \nInfection time: {perf_counter() - time2} \nPlacing time: {time2-time1}")
print(population_list.count(1), population_list.count(0))
```

numpy version

```
import random
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter
infected, non_infected = 1, 99999
infectation_chance, infection_days, death_chance = 1/100, 2/1000, 2/100

place = 10
population = infected + non_infected
group_size = population//place

population_list=np.zeros((population))
population_list[:infected]=1

day = 1
simulation_duration = 3

while 0 < simulation_duration:
    print(f"Working on day {day}..")
    time1 = perf_counter()
    # shuffle is not recursive so we need to flatten population_list
    population_list=population_list.flatten()
    np.random.shuffle(population_list)
    population_list=population_list.reshape((place, group_size))
    time2 = perf_counter()
    
    # we need to rebuild the pure python code with no loops
    # first we create randoms for all pop
    randoms = np.random.rand(population).reshape((place, group_size))
    
    # list of infected by group: a list of all p[i].count(1)
    nb_infected = np.count_nonzero(population_list, axis=1).reshape((place,1))
    # compute (1-infectation_chance**p[i].count(1)) for all pop
    infection_map=np.full((place, group_size), 1-infectation_chance)**nb_infected
    # if randoms>infection_map and population_list==0
    new_infected = np.bitwise_and(randoms>infection_map, population_list==0)
    # then set to 1 in place
    population_list[new_infected] = 1
                    
    simulation_duration -= 1
    day += 1
    print(f"Total time: {perf_counter() - time1} \nInfection time: {perf_counter() - time2} \nPlacing time: {time2-time1}")
total_infected=np.count_nonzero(population_list)
print(total_infected, population-total_infected)
```

Comment: Much appreciated, could a get a brief explanation on the part I need from NumPy. Also everything is perfect with the pure python part.

Comment: Also any help with the chance calculation as if there are more people the chance should go up but in the way I did it random.random()>(1-infectation_chance * pi_infected) if higher than 100 chances are 100% will get infected

Comment: with numpy you can reshape `population` into `p` shape and shuffle it very fast, now that your new bottleneck is placing time it should be noticeable. i guess that my infectation formula is wrong yes, maybe `random.random()>(1-infectation_chance)**pi_infected` is better

Comment: I still not understand how am I supposed to integrate NumPy, if you don't mind could you give me an example. Also I will try the new infection chance algorithm soon. @diggusbickus

Comment: Hey, it isnt made for the updated version only old one.... also the idea is that it randomly puts persons in places, I do not want the same number of persons in each room, if u dont mind check the newer version and repair that part. If you dont want to, you will still have the good answer thing, thanks for the help provided until now<3.